# Merge 3 dictionary to one in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Merge 3 dictionary to one. Each id has one element(`id`) as common

d1 is below

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui"
  }]
```

d2

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "Level":"Gold"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Level":"Silver"
  }]
```

d3

```
 [{
    "id": 1,
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "completed": true
  }]
```

Expected out

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "Level":"Gold",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "Level":"Silver"
    "completed": true
]
```

Comment: `false` and `true` need to be `False` and `True` for python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with list comprehension:

```
[{**a, **b, **c} for a, b, c in zip(d1, d2, d3)]
```

The output is:

```
[{'id': 1, 'title': 'delectus aut autem', 'Level': 'Gold', 'completed': False},
 {'id': 2,
  'title': 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui',
  'Level': 'Silver',
  'completed': True}]
```

Note that this assumes that all the three lists:

- Are sorted by ID. If this is not the case, sort them first using (for example): `l3 = sorted(l3, key=lambda x:x["id"])`.
- Contains items for all the IDs.

Comment: If list is not sorted based on ``id`` might yield wrong results.

Answer (score 3):

Here is pandas way of doing it, using [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge)

```
import pandas as pd

print(
    pd.DataFrame(df1).merge(pd.DataFrame(df2), on=['id'])
        .merge(pd.DataFrame(df3), on=['id'])
        .to_dict(orient='records')
)
```

---

```
[{'id': 1, 'title': 'delectus aut autem', 'Level': 'Gold', 'completed': False}, 
 {'id': 2, 'title': 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui', 'Level': 'Silver', 'completed': False}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work on a sorted/unsorted list.

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

merged_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for d in itertools.chain(d1, d2, d3):
    merged_dict[d["id"]].update(d)
 
final_list = list(merged_dict.values())

print(final_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "Level": "Gold",
        "completed": False
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
        "Level": "Silver",
        "completed": True,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Merging 3 dictionary

```
d = [] # merged dictionary
for (dict1, dict2, dict3) in zip(d1, d2, d3):
    k = 'id' # matching key
    if (dict1[k] == dict2[k] == dict3[k]):
        del dict2[k], dict3[k] # deleting common element from 2nd and 3rd
        dict1.update(dict2)    # merge 2nd in 1st
        dict1.update(dict3)    # merge 3rd in 1st
        d.append(dict(dict1))  # adding in array
print (d)
```

output:

> [{'id': 1, 'title': 'delectus aut autem', 'Level': 'Gold', 'completed': False}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui', 'Level': 'Silver', 'completed': True}]